# AlertController view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: swift, xcode

i am a beginner in swift, i was trying to use an **UIAlertController** but i have got an error and the **UiAlertController** do not show up and i can see an error in the console that says

```
2021-06-20 18:16:28.494162+0200 Bicycall[50670:543648] [Presentation] Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7fbaca034e00> on <Bicycall.login: 0x7fbabb01d800> (from <Bicycall.login: 0x7fbabb01d800>) whose view is not in the window hierarchy.
2021-06-20 18:16:28.494339+0200 Bicycall[50670:543648] [Presentation] Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7fbac9862800> on <Bicycall.login: 0x7fbabb01d800> (from <Bicycall.login: 0x7fbabb01d800>) whose view is not in the window hierarchy.
```

Here what i have tried:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import AVKit
import AVFoundation
import TKSubmitTransition

class login: UIViewController {

    
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailView: UIView!
    var id: Int?
    var name: String?
    var lastname: String?
    var email:String?
    var password:String?
    var phone:String?
    
    var u = ConnectedUser()
    var BR = BaseUrl.baseUrl
    
    var player: AVPlayer?
        let videoURL: NSURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Bikers", withExtension: "mp4")! as NSURL
    
    


    func getTopMostViewController() -> UIViewController? {
        var topMostViewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController

        while let presentedViewController = topMostViewController?.presentedViewController {
            topMostViewController = presentedViewController
        }

        return topMostViewController
    }

    
    
    func presentTestAlert(_ title: String, _ message: String){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title , message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("OK", comment: "Default action"), style: .default, handler: { _ in
        NSLog("The \"OK\" alert occured.")
        }))
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.getTopMostViewController()?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    }
 
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.DeleteAllData()
        
        
        player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL as URL)
                player?.actionAtItemEnd = .none
                player?.isMuted = true
                
                let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
                playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
                playerLayer.zPosition = -1
                playerLayer.frame = view.frame
                view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
                player?.play()
                NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.player?.currentItem, queue: .main) { [weak self] _ in
                                    self?.player?.seek(to: CMTime.zero)
                                    self?.player?.play()
        
        
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
        
        
                emailView.layer.cornerRadius = 30.0
                emailView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
        emailView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
                
                passwordView.layer.cornerRadius = 30.0
                passwordView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
                passwordView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    }
    
    
    
    //widgets
    
    @IBOutlet weak var txtEmail: UITextField!
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var txtPassword: UITextField!
    
    
    
    //Actions
    @IBAction func btnLogin(_ sender: Any){

         //get
       /*
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:3000/bikes") else {
        return
        }
        let session = URLSession.shared
        session.dataTask(with: url)  { ( data , response ,error) in
            if let response = response {
                print(response)
            }
            
            if let data = data {
                print(data)
                do
                {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                    print(json)
                }catch{
                    print(error)
                }
            }
            
        }.resume()
        */
        
        //post
    
        guard let url = URL(string: BR+"/login") else {
        return
        }
        
        let bodyparameters = ["email": txtEmail.text, "password": txtPassword.text]
       
        if (txtEmail.text!.isEmpty || txtPassword.text!.isEmpty ){
            
            self.presentTestAlert("Wrong credentials","Email and Password must not be empty")
            
        }else{

            
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: bodyparameters, options: []) else{
                return
                }
            request.httpBody = httpBody
            let session = URLSession.shared
            session.dataTask(with: request) { (data,response,error) in
                let status = (response as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode
                //print(response)
                print(status)
                if let response = response {
                    let status = (response as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode
                    //print(response)
                    print(status)
                }
                
                if((status) == 200){
                    self.presentTestAlert("Connection Success", " internet connection")
                    print(" Connection Successssssssssssssss")
                    
                    if let data = data {
                        do {
                            //let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                           // print(json);
                            print(data)
                            let user = try JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: data)
                           
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                
                                self.id = user.user_id
                                self.name = user.name
                                self.lastname = user.lastname
                                self.email = user.email
                                self.password = user.password
                                self.phone = user.phone
                                
                                print(self.id!)
                                print(self.email!)
                                
                                
                                if(user.user_id != 0){
                                   
                                    self.saveUser()
                                    self.DisplayConnectedUser()
                                   self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "HomeSegue", sender: "nil")
                                    
                                }else{
                                    self.presentTestAlert("Login Failed","Wrong credentials")
                                  
                                }
                            
                            }
                            
                        }catch{
                            print(error)
                        }
                        
                    }
                    
                }else {
                    self.presentTestAlert("No Connection", "No internet connection")
                    print(" Connection Nooooooooooooooooooooooooo")
                }
                
       
                
            }.resume()

            
            
        }
        
        
    }
    
    
    func DeleteAllData(){

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let DelAllReqVar = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Users"))
        do {
            try managedContext.execute(DelAllReqVar)
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    

    func saveUser() {
        
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        //represente l'ORM
        let persistentContainer = appDelegate.persistentContainer
        let managedContext = persistentContainer.viewContext
        
        let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Users" ,  in: managedContext)
        let object = NSManagedObject(entity: entityDescription! , insertInto: managedContext )
        object.setValue(id!  ,  forKey: "user_id"  )
        object.setValue(email!  ,  forKey: "email"  )
        object.setValue(password!  ,  forKey: "password"  )
        object.setValue(name!  ,  forKey: "name"  )
        object.setValue(lastname!  ,  forKey: "lastname"  )
        object.setValue(phone!  ,  forKey: "phone"  )
        
                  do {
                  
                 try managedContext.save()
                   print("INSERT SUCCESSFULLY")
                print(id!)
                   }
                   catch  {
                   print("INSERT ERROR")
                   }
        
    }
    

    
    
    @IBAction func btnSignup(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "signupSegue", sender: "nil")
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
      
    }

    
    
    func DisplayConnectedUser() {
            
             let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
                //represente l'ORM
                let persistentContainer = appDelegate.persistentContainer
                
                let managedContext = persistentContainer.viewContext     //retourne NSManagedObject toujours
                
                //la requete retourne un NSManagedObject
                let request = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName :   "Users")
                
                //execution de la requete
                do {
                
                    let result = try  managedContext.fetch(request)
                for item in result {
                    print(item.value(forKey: "user_id") as! Int )
                    print(item.value(forKey: "email")  as! String)
                    self.u.user_id  = (item.value(forKey: "user_id")  as! Int)
                    self.u.email = (item.value(forKey: "email")  as! String)
                    self.u.password = (item.value(forKey: "password")  as! String)
                    self.u.name = (item.value(forKey: "name")  as! String)
                    self.u.lastname = (item.value(forKey: "lastname")  as! String)
                    self.u.phone = (item.value(forKey: "phone")  as! String)
                   
                    print(self.u.user_id!)
                    print(self.u.email!)
                    print(self.u.password!)
                    print(self.u.name!)
                    print(self.u.lastname!)
                    print(self.u.phone!)
                  
                }
                
                   }
                   catch {
                   print("NO DATA FOUND , Error")
                   }


        }
    
    
    

}
```

What is annoying me is that none of my alerts worked! i read some other answer in stackoverflow but the solutions did not work for me

What i am trying is to make my alerts working good

Any help will be so appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to present the alert over the video player (`playerLayer`) but you are calling your alert over the layer behind the `playerLayer`, it will give you the error that you're getting.

With reference to [Swift 4 Attempt to present ViewController whose view is not in the window hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54209766/swift-4-attempt-to-present-viewcontroller-whose-view-is-not-in-the-window-hierar/54211295)

Add this function in your code

```swift
func getTopMostViewController() -> UIViewController? {
    var topMostViewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController

    while let presentedViewController = topMostViewController?.presentedViewController {
        topMostViewController = presentedViewController
    }

    return topMostViewController
}
```

And replace (Line 33)

```swift
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

with

```swift
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    getTopMostViewController()?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: hi , thank you for the answer but it did not work properly because after i executed the condition of checking if the email or password stopped working while it was working before i add your code , it is like when i click on the button the app ignores the if conditions after i added your code, i updated my post

Comment: yes but the segue is performed in all the cases , it was not happening before your code

Comment: Can you check if email and password are actually empty in your else block?

Comment: no , after your code , the else block do not work properly

Comment: I don’t know why the `if; else` block is not working. The issue with the alert is I guess solved, you need to see what is going wrong in the `if; else` block